# ionic2 navbar back button css

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am a beginner of using ionic 2, I am faced the issue to change the color of back button text color, i have added a css like below:

```
ion-header ion-icon.back-button-icon.icon{
   color: #17B97D;
}
```

But only the arrow changed to the color I wanted the text "Back" not change.

[image]

Does anyone know how to change it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add that element to your css rule, like this:

```
ion-header ion-icon.back-button-icon.icon, 
ion-header span.back-button-text.back-button-text-ios {
   color: #17B97D;
}
```